# Repeated variable length regexp matching

Tags: regex

I have an expression

```
AA-BB/CC/DD
```

I want to convert this to

```
<AA-BB> <AA-CC> <AA-DD>
```

All I can do is configure this as a regexp substitution. I can't figure it out.

AA should match at the beginning of a line. `-` and `/` are literal characters, BB,CC and DD are numbers, i.e `\d+`

So a first draft is ...

```
^(\w+)([\-/]\d+)+
```

but I want all matches, not just the greedy one.

(actually this one matches AA-BB-CC-DD too, but that's ok although it's not according to spec)

Comment: What is your language to do this?

Comment: is the number of tags fixed?

Comment: no it's any number of tags, but an upper-bounded, say ten would be much bettr than what I have now

Comment: I want this to work for javascript, java and perl. I.e. there are three similar applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with regex. Probably with .net, because there you can access all intermediate results of repeated capturing groups ...

[Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html)

That is the problem, if you do something like `^(\w+)([\-/]\w+)+` the value stored in group2 is always only the last pattern it matched. Your task is not possible with regex/replace.

I would do something like:

```
^(\w+)-([\w+\/]+)
```

Then split the content of group 2 by "/" and combine group1 with each element of the array resulting from the split.

Comment: I lean towards beleiving you.